# Using ServiceStack Ormlite global filters with Session

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to alter the example found [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#global-insert--update-filters) so that modifyby is populated with the session's username every time a change is made. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need singleton access to access the UserName which you would need to populate in either the `ReqeustContext` or ASP.NET's `HttpContext.Current.Items` Dictionary, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req,res,dto) => {
    RequestContext.Instance.Items["UserName"] = req.GetSession().UserAuthName;
});
```

Which you can access from inside your `UpdateFilter`, e.g:

```
OrmLiteConfig.UpdateFilter = (dbCmd, row) => {
    var auditRow = row as IAudit;
    var userName = RequestContext.Instance.Items["UserName"] as string;
    if (auditRow != null)
        auditRow.UserName = userName;
};
```

Note: the "UserName" will only work within the context of a HTTP Request.